# Python package name conflict

Tags: python

I have (ended up with) my packages being setup in the following way. There are two packages with the same name, but one of them is inside `package_a`.

```
    ├── package_a/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── package_aa/
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── module_a.py
    │   └── module_c.py
    └── package_aa/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module_b.py
```

How do I import both `module_a.py` and `module_b.py` in my code? The following

```py
from package_a.package_aa import module_a; from package_aa import module_b;
```

fails with the error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'module_b' from 'package_aa' (.\package_a\package_aa\__init__.py)
```

All `__init__.py` files contain a single line

```py
import os, sys; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Renaming is unfortunately not an option as I am not the owner of these packages.

---

EDIT : Swapping works. Thanks. I have a follow up question : Suppose in `module_c.py`, `modula_a.py` is imported like this `from package_aa import module_a`. Then the following fail with similar error, but it is not as apparent (to the user) as in the original question

```py
from package_aa import module_b; from package_a import module_c
```

How can the owner of `package_a` modify it so that its users don't run into errors like this? I am starting to think, the way `__init__.py` is written might not be right. Although, I have seen answers elsewhere which suggests adding `sys.path.append` or `sys.path.insert` in this fashion.

Comment: Try swapping these round i.e. `from package_aa import module_b; from package_a.package_aa import module_a; `?

Comment: "`import os, sys; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))`": it's generally a bad idea if a package modifies sys.path to insert its directory. This should really be done, if at all, on a user/system level, not by the package itself. But ideally (and normally), the package is installed in a place where it is already automatically picked up by Python.

Comment: I think just append the full path (sys.append) of each package to your execution file will be ok.

Comment: @goblinshark : Thanks, it works.
@9769953 : Thanks. I have added a follow up question in the edit. What is the right way to import `module_a` in `module_c`?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to swap them like this:

```
from package_aa import module_b
from package_a.package_aa import module_a
```

This way, package_aa is not referenced in the path.